# selecting from multiple tables in SQL without a join

Tags: sql

Complete SQL novice, trying to make sense of the following TPC-H query:

```
select
        l_orderkey,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as revenue,
        o_orderdate,
        o_shippriority
from
        customer,
        orders,
        lineitem
where
        c_mktsegment = ':1'
        and c_custkey = o_custkey
        and l_orderkey = o_orderkey
        and o_orderdate < date ':2'
        and l_shipdate > date ':2'
group by
        l_orderkey,
        o_orderdate,
        o_shippriority
order by
        revenue desc,
        o_orderdate;
:n 10
```

I was under the impression that you can only select from different tables after a join. However I don't see any joins here. Is it implicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is archaic syntax for the `CROSS JOIN`.  It is essentially the same thing as a Cartesian product (although the scoping rules in the `FROM` clause are a bit different).

The filter conditions in the `WHERE` clause happen to turn this Cartesian product into an inner join, but that is a function of the filtering *after* the `FROM` clasue.

You should just forget that you every learned that this syntax works.  Use explicit `JOIN` syntax, even for `CROSS JOIN`.  `JOIN` has been part of SQL syntax -- literally -- for decades and it was added for very good reasons.